# Failed to load JDBC Template that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc

In my `SpringBoot` application, I have a service defined as:

```
@Service
public class JdbcService {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public DataSource myDatabase;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(">>run()");
        jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(stagingDatabase);
        jdbcTemplate.execute("INSERT SAMPLETABLE1 (STRING1, STRING2) VALUES ('TEST1', 'TEST2)");
        System.out.println("<<run()");
    }
}
```

I get:

```
Description:

Field jdbcTemplate in com.myproject.services.JdbcService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' in your configuration.
```

When I add `@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.myproject")`
to my SpringBootApplication defined in this package, I also get it.

build.gradle includes:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add the following dependency in your pom.xml                                                                         <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: @Shaan Yes, I have updated the question

Comment: How does your application.properties look like ?

Comment: Can you try adding @EnableAutoConfiguration in SpringBootApplication class also need to be defined connection properties in the property file.

Answer (score 2):

I had to define it as a Bean.  I also renamed it to make it clearer.

```
@Configuration
public class DatasourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    JdbcTemplate dwJdbcTemplate() {
            JdbcTemplate dwDatasource = new JdbcTemplate(dwDatasource());
            return dwDatasource;
    }
}
```